# how to set the cost parameter of SVM as a function of the sample size?

Tags: svm, regularization

this is a follow up to:

[SVM parameter dependence on number of samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101131/svm-parameter-dependence-on-number-of-samples)

please, is there any progress since the above post was answered, with respect to literature or current practice, on how to set C in SVM?

are there research papers detailing how C should decay as a function of the number of samples in the training set?

according to the above post,

> The $C$ parameter for most SVM implementations scales approximately
> linearly with the number of training patterns, so if you train with a
> subset, you will need to multiply $C$ by a factor of $N_s/N_t$ where
> $N_t$ is the number of training patterns and $N_s$ is the subset size
> for the parameter optimization.  This is only an approximation though,
> so it may not give as good an estimate as performing model selection
> with the full training set.

are there any more specific details about this answer? by the way, in the above comment, should we replace $N_s/N_t$  by $N_t/N_s$?